# expiration date of decoded token from firebase compared to Date.now()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, refresh-token

I am using **jwtDecode** package to decode firebase refresh-token so i am getting an object like this:

```
aud: "app name"
auth_time: 1596323784
email: "any email"
email_verified: false
exp: 1596327384
firebase: {identities: {…}, sign_in_provider: "password"}
iat: 1596323784
iss: "https://securetoken.google.com/app name"
user_id: "8mV0nvPuv3ctsZxegS5Sz4uwshP2"
```

I want to compare expiration date always to `Date.now()` so when the token expires the user redirected to **login** page but what confuses me is that `Date.now()` has a bigger value than `exp*1000` of a fresh token,

```
if(decodedToken.exp * 1000 > Date.now()) {
 authenticated = true
} else {
  authenticated = false;
  window.location.href="/login"
}
```

now this piece of code cause the page redirect every second to login page and never get to home page and i need to change **>** to **<** which is counter-intuitive for me .

Shouldn't expiration date value be bigger than the returned value of **Date.now()** till the token expires

Comment: FYI: the Firebase Auth SDK automatically refreshes the user's token every hour as needed.  Normally developers allow that to keep the user signed in for as long as they like.  I'm curious why you are trying to do something different.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am not trying to do something different, i want the user keep signed in and even when click login link in the navbar not directed to the login page, my question now, shouldn't expiration date be after ```date.now() ``` till the token expires.

Comment: You don't have to write any code to keep the user signed in.  As I said, it happens automatically, as long as you don't sign them out.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok you are right, but why that happens?? the new token exp is  < date.now()..would be thankful if you clarified that to me

Answer (score 1):

That might just be an integer overflow error - try writing it like this instead:

```
if(decodedToken.exp  > Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) {
}
```

It is not good practice to read expiry times of tokens though, since tokens can be rejected by APIs for other reasons, such as revocation and clock differences between client and server.

Doing this works better:

- Access token is considered expired when a 401 status is received from the API
- You then try to refresh the access token at the Authorization Server - then retry the API call with the new access token
- Eventually refresh will fail in which case the Authorization Server will return an invalid_grant error code
- This error code means end of session and you then need to redirect the user to sign in again

Here is some example code in a React sample of mine to compare against:

- [API calls](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts)
- [OAuth expiry](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts)

Comment: Thanks Gary, but still this nasty problem exist, date.now() is still bigger!.

Comment: Maybe the token exp claim has an unexpected value then. Perhaps use an [online tool](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to compare the token's exp claim to the current epoch time. If the exp claim is not in the future as expected then it could be some kind of configuration problem - or even an incorrect vendor implementation. If so it is not a blocking issue - I've worked with OAuth for quite a few years and never felt the need to check token expiry times.

Comment: can the problem be because my local time, i am using firebase cloud function which is ```europe-west1``` and i am in the middle east, can this be the problem, because when i am using postman to mimic requests using tokens it always return a message saying that i use expiered token but when i am creating the actual request to firebase this doesn't happen??